# Как определять, какие объекты (по тегам) задевает рэйкаст? Unity 2D C#

Tags: c#

Суть проста... Как сделать условие, которое бы срабатывало при касании рэйкастом объекта/-ов с определённым тегом. Вместо `if(raycast.colider != null){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, как-то так:

```
if(raycast.colider != null && raycast.colider.gameObject.tag == "someTag") {
   ...
}
```

код не проверялся, так что возможны некоторые ошибки, но идея эта.

Comment: Спасибо большое!